# Reading CRS from shapefile and plotting with Cartopy

Tags: python, coordinate-system, shapefile, geopandas, cartopy

I read a shapefile containing geometries that I want to plot using Cartopy. My challenge is finding the correct CRS projection to use for this. The `.prj` file contains this information:

> PROJCS["NAD_1983_Albers",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Albers"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-154.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",55.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",65.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",50.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

When I plot the shapefile in Google Earth it looks correct,
[image: Google Earth with correct projection]

but when I plot using Cartopy it is off
[image: Cartopy with wrong projection]

I obviously use the incorrect projection (`crs.AlbersEqualArea` assumed from `PROJECTION["Albers"]`), but I am not sure how to identify the correct one from the `.prj` file.

How can I extract the necessary information and plot the shapefile using Cartopy without having to guess the projection? I would welcome any suggestions.

The shapefile is found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/azv6wasnx3eyb8n/AAB56bXeRGqe7ay7HBPmg3Nna?dl=0) if anyone would take a look and the code for making the map is here:

```py
import geopandas as gdp

def create_colors(N):
   color = iter(cm.tab20b(np.linspace(0,1,N)))
   return [next(color) for c in range(N)]

ax.coastlines(resolution="10m", linewidth=0.6, color="black", alpha=0.8, zorder=4)
ax.add_feature(cpf.BORDERS, linestyle=':',alpha=0.4)
ax.add_feature(cpf.LAND, color="orange")
extent = [-182, -100, 40, 65]

projection = ccrs.AlbersEqualArea(central_longitude=-155,
                        central_latitude=50,
                        standard_parallels=(0, 80))

ax.set_extent(extent, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

shdf = gpd.read_file(lme_file)

LMES = ["630","640","650","620","610"]
counter = 0
for LME_NUMBER in shdf['NMFS_AREA']:

    shdf_sel = shdf[shdf['NMFS_AREA']==LME_NUMBER]
    ax.add_geometries(shdf_sel['geometry'],
                          projection,
                          facecolor='LightGray',
                          edgecolor='k')

plt.show()
```

I managed to get the projection correct by manually adding the optional parameters to Albers Equal Area projection in Cartopy.

```py
projection = ccrs.AlbersEqualArea(central_longitude=-154, central_latitude=50, false_easting=0, false_northing=0)
```

This gives a nice result like this:
[image]

I still would like to know if there are any way I could have extracted this information automatically from the shapefile without having to manually look into the `.prj` file, but regardless this works.

Answer (score 3):

This turned out to be pretty straightforward when usin GeoPandas. I first converted the shapefile to a standard projection (EPSG:4326):

```py
import geopandas as gpd

shdf = gpd.read_file("shapefile")
shdf = shdf.to_crs("EPSG:4326")
```

Next, I used the `PlateCarree`as my projection in Cartopy. I could then add my shapefile geometries using:

```py
ax = plt.figure(figsize=(16,10)).gca(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines(resolution=res, linewidth=0.6, color="black", alpha=0.8, zorder=4)
ax.add_feature(cpf.BORDERS, linestyle=':', alpha=0.4, zorder=2)
ax.add_feature(cpf.LAND, color="lightgrey", zorder=2)
projection = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=0) 
ax.add_geometries(shdf.geometry,
                  projection,
                  facecolor="red",
                  edgecolor='k')
```

Reading the documentation of [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/) was very useful.